# Form to Set body of E-mail via mailto in E-Mail Newsletter

Tags: html, forms, email, mailto

Is there something we're missing to get the following code working in E-Mail clients / Web Mail:

```
<form action="mailto:a@b.com">
<input type="hidden" name="Subject" value="Email subject">
<textarea style="resize:none;" rows="5" cols="22" value="Body" name="Body">Default text area</textarea><br />
<input type="submit" name="Ask Question" >
</form>
```

The idea is that the recipient can ask a question of our team by typing their question into a text area ('Body') and clicking the button will open their default mail client/web mail with the message nicely composed for them to review and click send.

Clearly any kind of PHP or scripting is off limits as this strictly to be used in an e-mail newsletter template.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this one  with

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=MySubject&body=Mymessage"> Send mail </a>
```

you need to get the message and subject value from form and add that in link .  also try to use with your form

```
<form action="mailto:myforms@mydomain.com" enctype="text/plain" >
```

also  you can try this one

```
<form action= "mailto:myforms@mydomain.com?subject=myform_submission" enctype="text/plain" onsubmit="location.href='thanks.html';" >
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, not sure I understand it though. The code I posted above works in a web page in browsers as its intended to but does not work in e-mail.

Comment: Thanks for your response. PHP code would be what I would normally use however its not suitable for e-mail in this case. Even if I could call to a hosted PHP script, thee is so much red tape in the company that this is for that it would not get passed this century!

Comment: by the php code you have no need to open the web mail like this  you just filll the  text in box and mail id and on submit mail will automatically send to the user mail id

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by mail ID. I've always been under the impression that PHP can not be used in E-Mail.

Comment: i mean to say that  you have  one  text field to  enter mail and other to add  message    and after submition  you  get the mail on  your entered mail  with the text you enter in message box  and its possible  on live server to send mail

Comment: it's possible to do that on a web page yes by way of PHP but not possile when the mailto link is in an e-mail. The HTML above is sent to customers in an HTML E-Mail. So requires a different approach, even if its possible.